# SSAS Cube, limit the results based on count

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-2012

My users will have access to our SSAS cubes through excel where they can slice and dice and interact dynamically with the cube. Due to privacy constraints, I am **not** allowed to return result sets with counts of 10 or below. *For example,* if the combination of filters together is going to bring back results belonging to a sub-populattion with less than 10 people , then i should return nothing or maybe an error message even (for this example assume each row represents one person). I am not even sure where to start with this request, is this even possible in cubes when the users interact dynamically with the cube using excel? I know that if you are creating a SINGLE MDX-based report, you could always write a condition and limit the result to those **WHERE COUNT>x**. But is there a way to do this in Excel? If so, then if someone could steer me in the right direction and give me a topic, I could do more work on it. But after hours of searching, I just don't know where to begin. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: why not just build your cube from Views that filter out that data?

Comment: @whytheq how's that possible? a combination of filters can yield to a small resultset. I think you may have overlooked the question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you **can't** do this in Excel, or by using any kind of cube/dimension/cell-level security.  Those security features are very powerful, but they work by specifying regions in the cube structure (dimension members, tuples, cells) that are allowed/not allowed.  They're all about *location* (e.g. the "very secret and sensitive medical trial" member of the Trials dimension, or the "North Korea" member of the Geography dimension), not about *content*.

Is there any mileage in changing the granularity of the cube to be coarser, and only hold facts in groups of 10?  My mind boggles at the difficulty of doing that, though.

I think that this requirement contradicts something basic about the nature of multi-dimensional cubes, which is that they don't "know" (pre-aggregate) what queries might be thrown at them, or what the results might be.  (OK, they do pre-aggregate, but only a tiny subset of the possible combinations).  So they're naturally very bad at controlling access to data based on the *result*.  That's what gives an open querying tool like Excel PivotTables its power: you can do anything, whatever the results might be (empty, large, small).

This is horribly difficult requirement to implement.  It negates the whole idea of cubes, which encourage speculative dives into the data.  It may be a distorted manifestation (after much political wrangling) of a genuine concern for privacy, which you've been landed with.  Can this concern perhaps be met elsewhere?  If you - and possibly other developers and testers - are trusted to see this data at the leaf level (you have to, to be able to develop and test), then why are at least a subset of users not trusted to see it?

It sounds like a failure of other processes (recruitment, screening, trust in employees) that you're being landed with, rather than a genuine achievable requirement.  It reminds me of Maciej Ceglowski's description of data as "toxic waste" - you're tasked to collect all this data (because data is the ultimate good, remember?), but then you're asked to jump through impossible hoops to stop it being used!